# Car insurance gas station mix-up fuels -- gas station made the mistake

Tags: car, insurance

We rented a car with Hertz and we filled up our tank with petrol and later on that day our car broke down. The road side assistance people told us the next day that we put diesel instead of petrol in our car.
We went back to the gas station and they found our receipt showing we filled up our tank with petrol. Then they told us, that they mixed up diesel and petrol at the gas station. So, it's quite a mess there, but we do not know if they are going to go public with this. They told us that over **350** cars must have been affected.

The petrol station is the a Q8 Petrol Station in Italy near Ancona.
It seems really strange to me that there is nothing in the news yet. I tried to contact newspapers but I did not receive any attention. Any tips when contacting the press?

The gas station is trying to avoid the direct blame, instead blaming the truck driver who filled the station.

Do you know if Hertz will make us pay for the gas station's mistake? We have a full insurance from Booking.com, not from Hertz directly. One issue here is that we cannot apparently contact Hertz head office before they contact us with a claim for us to pay the excess, which could take up to 90 days. It is in fact likely that they will make us pay for the **excess** for repair costs. We have no way to explain the situation to them really.

The gas station is not very responsive and it looks like that we will have to take a lawyer and sue them, which is very annoying because I don't live in Italy, so I will have to do it from abroad.

Comment: When a car rental company charges for damages you should also expect them to charge for the missed rental periods. That is what makes the damages when a renter is in an accident so expensive.

Comment: How do you estimate €500? If Hertz does replace the engine and holds you responsible, that would be a lot more than €500, right? Have you given Hertz a copy of the fuel receipt? A key step may be whether the gas station is contacted by Hertz and admits *to Hertz* that they provided the wrong fuel. If you think publicity is useful, consider contacting a local news outlet. There's a decent chance that one of the 150 other drivers may have done so, and you may hear, "Yes, we're already working on a story." Or a good journalist could turn up some of the other people affected even if you can't.

Comment: @nanoman I tried to contact some newspaper about the story but so far I haven't receive any attention. Do you have any tips for contacting the press?

Answer (score 2):

It could take a while to resolve and there are several ways it could go.

I hope you are obtaining whatever evidence you can when speaking to the gas station (a copy of your receipt, the name of the employee who acknowledged the mistake, etc.).

Do you know the total amount you will be asked to pay if no one else takes responsibility? Would this be just the roadside assistance charge? Has the fuel system already been drained and refilled with petrol? Is there lasting damage to the engine that Hertz could ding you for?

First, Hertz *might* simply waive the charges as good customer service.

Next, your insurance (from Booking.com or perhaps from the credit card you used to rent the car) may cover this. Whether that works by you paying Hertz and the insurance reimbursing you, or whether Hertz will work directly with the insurance, you will have to find out. If the insurance might object that the costs are excluded due to negligence by you, then you can point them to the gas station.

If you end up having to pay costs that weren't your fault, you could try suing the gas station in small claims court.

Comment: @giac Has Hertz already accepted the car back and confirmed that they are not holding you responsible for, e.g., an engine replacement?

Comment: Not yet, they said the investigation about what is wrong with the car is ongoing. But we have the awkward situation that we have a receipt showing we put petrol but we have a car with diesel in it! Crazy situation. I never found this situation on the internet. Must be super rare!

Answer (score -3):

Is this is in the USA the next step is a certainty.

1. Contact a lawyer, ideally in the town where the gas station is.
2. Explain what happened.

They will immediately begin a "small" class action lawsuit against the station / petrol brand.

Note that, as well as the fact that you will get 10s of thousands from the lawsuit, this will instantly ***make it a matter of record*** that the gas station was to blame, for you and the other 200 people.

At the moment, all you have is an "assertion".  You'll be telling some minimum-wage worker on the telephone "oh, the gas station made a mistake". They will reply "Send us $12,000 for a new engine."

It's incredibly simple, in the US, to find aggressive litigation attorneys in each city - go for it.

For the time it takes you to make a phone call, you can completely turn the situation around.

Comment: 1. Before suing, OP will at least want to make sure they know all their costs (e.g., what amount Hertz is demanding for repairs). 2. Some people may want to try resolving amicably and reserve a lawsuit for a last resort, because prospective employers/landlords may see a history of filing lawsuits (however well-justified) as a red flag on a background check.

Comment: hi @nanoman - but the two issues you expressed, are, *precisely what a lawyer does*.  In very few cases will it "go to court".   The two items you express cannot be tackled by a civilian.  (If you or I or the OP called Large Petrol Brand to discuss those two issues, the 15th-level employee who answered the phone would: hang up.) This is why lawyers exist.

Comment: This can easily backfire. If enough cars are affected it may bankrupt the gas station and after (substantial) lawyer's fees there is nothing left for you.

Comment: Agreed, no harm in *consulting* a lawyer. But the lawyer might advise first to "give them (Hertz and gas station) a chance to do the right thing". Once companies are contacted through legal channels, yes, they pay attention, but they typically go into "stonewall" mode and don't give an inch without a battle -- where otherwise they might have given a goodwill gesture. Another non-legal-system option is contacting a journalist, some of whom specialize in troubleshooting (and publishing) consumer disputes.

Comment: I think that in Europe, we don't really sue companies like that. I think it is not as simple as in the US, and the gains are very limited in Europe. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: hi @giac  !  where did this happen - can you add a country info to the question?  Yes, if this happened in most parts of Europe, you're basically screwed.

Comment: I don't think screwed is necessarily correct. You might not need to "sue" a company for them to make the right move. I will keep you update if you are interested, but I bet that they will just let that slide and not ask us to pay. But we never know. My experience with Europe is that companies "do the right thing" when they screw up. But let's see. I found this story in the US by the way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvoY6wwMiyY

Comment: I think you might have been right that it is going to be a legal battle!